# Filling an array with country objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am programming the game of risk in java. I have a class called countries which will have an array filled with objects of type country. How do I fill the array with the 42 country objects. I am thinking maybe using a for loop to fill the array but I am not sure how to have it fill all the different countries.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Use an `ArrayList<Coutnry> countries`...... `coutries.add(new Country(...));`

Comment: @peeskillet I think the OP knows how to create a `List`, I think he is just looking for the best way to create all of the countries :P (Or at least that is how I'm interpreting it). If so, I would suggest creating an `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simplified way would be to use `ISO country codes`, [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Getalistofcountrynames.htm) provides an efficient way of handling it.

I have tweaked the code to handle the exception and bin the Comparator (working code below):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            try {
                String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
                String code = locale.getCountry();
                String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();

                if (!"".equals(iso) && !"".equals(code) && !"".equals(name)) {
                    countries.add(new Country(iso, code, name));
                }
            } catch (MissingResourceException ex) {

            }
        }

        for (Country country : countries) {
            System.out.println(country);
        }
    }
}

class Country {
    private String iso;

    private String code;

    public String name;

    Country(String iso, String code, String name) {
        this.iso = iso;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return iso + " - " + code + " - " + name.toUpperCase();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
MYS - MY - MALAYSIA
QAT - QA - QATAR
ISL - IS - ICELAND
FIN - FI - FINLAND
MLT - MT - MALTA
CHE - CH - SWITZERLAND
BEL - BE - BELGIUM
...
```